# How to remove cloud songs from Music app?

Tags: ios, icloud, music

During Christmas 2013, Apple an official app that gave out free downloads for a week or so. I used that app to get some free songs. Now they appear forever stuck in my Music app. I don't want to see them. Swiping left on the song didn't do anything. Also, I didn't see how to manage these songs in iTunes on my computer.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Launch the Settings app then go to "Music" and toggle the "Show All Music" switch to "Only music that has been downloaded to this device will be shown."

This same feature is available for the Video app.

Comment: I did that, but all it did was remove the cloud icon from each track.

Comment: That "should" mean that those tracks are now on your device, otherwise they should not be displayed. That is how it works for me.

Comment: I tried that. the same songs are or the list without the cloud sign. I want to delete them.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to press on the title of the song I wanted to delete, it then opened a menu with several options including downloading or deleting the song.

I haven't found a way to do it any faster though, which would be nice.